# Inaccuracy in decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I'm in the process of converting a programme I've made from using floats to decimals.

Obviously the main reason I'm doing this is for accuracy.

I haven't used decimal before so thought I'd have a play first. The first thing I did was this:

```
>>> x = Decimal(7.2)
>>> x
Decimal('7.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125')
```

Now considering decimals meant to be accurate and avoid long trailing numbers like floats, I was pretty surprised to see that happen. It's also gone to 50 D.P. despite the standard preset of 28 (and doesn't matter what you set the preset too.

Is this a bug (|feature)? And why is it happening?

Comment: In short - you're passing `Decimal` a `float`... use `'7.2'` a string - I'm sure there's a dupe for this :)

Comment: thanks, I'll make sure to use strs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Decimal(7.2)` will create a decimal from the exact value of the float `7.2`. Since the float is not precise, while `Decimal` is, creating the decimal will carry over the inaccuracies from the float into the decimal, yielding the result you see there.

To create the exact decimal of 7.2, you need to specify it as a string:

```
Decimal('7.2')
```

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot more sense now! (and kind of obvious)

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because you feed a float literal, that cannot be represented accurately in binary. You should provide a string:

```
Decimal('7.2')
```

or use integers:

```
Decimal(72) / 10
```